# PHPExcel - setTitle with variable not working

Tags: variables, phpexcel

When trying to use a variable to set worksheet name with PHPExcel it pulls up an error. Can anyone help?

Here is the code section I'm using:

```
for($i = 0;$i <= 9; $i++){
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $i);

   $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
   $objWorksheet->setTitle($i);

   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i); 
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 
     'Invalid character found in sheet title' in ...Worksheet.php:401 
Stack trace: 
   #0 ...Worksheet.php(657): PHPExcel_Worksheet::_checkSheetTitle(1) 
   #1 ...JH-auto-sheets.php(37): PHPExcel_Worksheet->setTitle(1) 
   #2 {main} thrown in ...Worksheet.php on line 401`
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some characters that PHPExcel won't allow you to use for tab titles, even if it's allowed within Excel itself.  I've experienced issues with the following characters, and make sure my tab titles don't contained these characters: `[]:?!/\*`

I discovered this through experience and process of elimination.  There may be more characters out there that will throw this error.  I just haven't found them yet.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use any of these characters `*:/\?[]` in the title.

Also the title has a maximum length of 31 characters, so you should check for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
  array (size=7)

  0 => string '*' (length=1)

  1 => string ':' (length=1)

  2 => string '/' (length=1)

  3 => string '\' (length=1)

  4 => string '?' (length=1)

  5 => string '[' (length=1)

  6 => string ']' (length=1)
```

you can not use this in your parameter

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem but was able to overcome it.

For some reason, setTitle will throw the exception "Invalid character found in sheet title" if your variable is not explicitly declared as a string.

So, in your example, change

```
`$objWorksheet->setTitle($i);`
```

to

```
`$objWorksheet->setTitle(strval($i));`
```